# javascript push json object to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following:

```
var cookie = $.cookie("Test_cookie");
var items = cookie ? eval("([" + cookie + "])") : [];
var jsonObj = { packageId: "11", machineId: "1", operationType: "Download" };
items.push(jsonObj);
$.cookie(cookieName, JSON.stringify(items), { expires: 1, path: '/' });
```

result:

```
[{"packageId":"11","machineId":"1","operationType":"Download"}]
```

which is correct.

However, when I run it the second time I want to append new object to items but json gets messed up (notice extra "["):

```
var jsonObj = { packageId: "11", machineId: "1", operationType: "Download" };
items.push(jsonObj);
$.cookie(cookieName, JSON.stringify(items), { expires: 1, path: '/' });
```

result:

```
[[{"packageId":"11","machineId":"1","operationType":"Download"}],{"packageId":"11","machineId":"1","operationType":"Download"}]
```

and it should be:

```
[{"packageId":"11","machineId":"1","operationType":"Download"},{"packageId":"11","machineId":"1","operationType":"Download"}]
```

what gives?

Comment: Some servers will alert you monthly by email - for suspicious scripts in your pages. Thanks to `eval()`

Comment: Try `console.log(items)` and paste output here.

Comment: @roXon - They should charge you monthly as well, for using eval!

Comment: @adeneo :D :D :D hahahahahah now I need another coffee ;) YMMD

Comment: I'm confused...why aren't you using `JSON.parse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is near

```
var items = cookie ? eval("([" + cookie + "])") : [];
```

Just do

```
var items = cookie ? eval(cookie) : [];
```

Comment: that did it!. thank you! I will accept your answer in 9 min :)

Comment: in that case the eval is quite unneeded (and dangerous tho) specially if used in combinations with cookies ;)

Comment: `JSON.parse` would be preferred over `eval`.

Comment: @JoelDuret now that you pointed it out I see I'm wrong, but in any case.... eval is not that evil if used smartly, but there's other ways to "evaluate" a string. There's always a way. using `eval()` is any attacker's dream and is sign of poor scripting

Comment: Joel, how would I pop from a list of json objects?

Comment: @roXon Ok, i agree with you for the security issue.

Comment: @ShaneKm In fact, items is not a JSON object, but a simple Javascript array of objects. Use pop() method to pop an element using its index.
Hope it'll be usefull!

Comment: how would i find the index?

Comment: You have two possiblities : if you have the object to pop, just find the index with : items.indexOf(popElement)  But if you don't have the object to pop, you have to loop for all elements, and to test if it's the good one.

Comment: [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) always yields the last element in the array; no index needed.